# Aspnetcode run with non-root user in linux

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to run a veery simple hello world aspnetcore application inside a docker image (that inherits from microsoft/aspnetcore) with non-root user and I'm getting this error:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>         Unable to start Kestrel. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -13 EACCES permission denied) --->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException:
>   Error -13 EACCES permission denied    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.ThrowError(Int32
>   statusCode)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle
>   handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress
>   address)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.b__8_0(Object
>   state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.ListenerPrimary.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress
>   address)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
>   application)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException:
>   Error -13 EACCES permission denied    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.ThrowError(Int32
>   statusCode)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle
>   handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress
>   address)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.b__8_0(Object
>   state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.ListenerPrimary.d__12.MoveNext()<---

It seems that aspnetcore could not be run without root permissions, and in some scenarios with very restricted security policies root user is not allow to run the main process of a docker image.

Is it any way to run aspnetcore application in linux with non-root user?

Sudo option is not valid becuase the same security policy.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Finally the problem was that I was trying to use port 80 for binding my app. If you use higher ports, ie, 5000. There are no problems with permissions.

Comment: That's how Linux work. For all ports <= 1024, you require root to bind to

Comment: On a side note, you should never run ASP.NET Core on port 80, since that's the port used by most webservers as default port. The question suggests you may try to directly expose the ASP.NET Core app to the internet. **Don't do that** Kestrel (for now) isn't supposed to act as internet facing server and is always to be run behind reverse proxy (apache, nginx, iis), only exception is WebListener which is approved for IFS, but it's windows-only

Comment: Hello can you share docker file how you have created non root user.   I was not able to run container without root user though non root user is there still running as root